# Java: Parsing xml file with DOM API

Tags: java, xml, dom, jaxb

I am trying to parse an XML file with 1000 elements using DOM API in Java. It takes 30 seconds to process the XML file.

1 element, for eg **store** is the root and it has around 15 children like store name, store count, store location, etc...

Is there any other API that can be used to make the whole thing faster?

How about using JAXB (I do not know much about JAXB but I am told by my peers to consider it)?

Comment: have you tried using SAX instead of DOM? Try Apache Digester library.

Comment: 30 seconds for 1000 elements seems excessive.
But the problem is probably in your "processing", not the API.
How big is the file? Can you provide some code?

Comment: What do you want to do with the parsed xml?

Comment: constructing Store objects and adding it to list..

Comment: the problem can be in your code , show it !

Answer (score 2):

A 30 second delay during parsing is usually caused by fetching the DTD from the web, especially if it's one of the standard DTDs (like XHTML) found on the w3C web site. If your XML references one of these DTDs you need to make sure that the parser is redirected to a local copy, by using catalogs.